# Hibernate LocalSessionFactrory VS HibernateTransactionManager

Tags: hibernate, spring, dependency-injection, struts2

I am implementing a application with Struts2 + Spring + Hibernate.

I would like to know what is the difference between using `LocalSessionFactory` alone in Spring's applicationContext.xml and using `HibernateTransactionManager`, having the `LocalSessionFactory` injected.

Comment: @ Steven Benitez @ Ralph Thanks to notify me... Really i dont know about that... Ill do it hereafter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode especially at *Working nontransactionally with Hibernate*